# Where does Ruby On Rails save data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and am going through their "getting started" tutorial on their website which leads you through making a blog.  When I write a blog post it's saved to a database with @article.save.  Anytime I go onto the website, I can see any of the past blog posts I have made so the data must be stored somewhere.  I was wondering where specifically in the blog folder this is stored at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is saved in `sqllite3` database locally.

You can find this file in `<app-folder/db/<env>.sqllite3.`. For example, `development.sqllite3`

The database configuration is typically present `<app-folder>/config/database.yml`. file.  By default, you will see below settings in it.

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

Comment: Just to expand on this, I've found [sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to be a useful tool for playing around with the database, for example if you need to modify certain records.